# Is there a way to publish data from master jenkins while executing on slave machine?

Tags: jenkins

I have a file on master `Jenkins` in path `/home/ubuntu/Build_number.txt` and my job is executing on `Jenkins` slave.

I want the data in one of the files which is stored on master jenkins to be published in email notification of slave job.

Subject in email notification is as :

```
Job_name - Build #${FILE,path="/home/ubuntu/Build_number.txt"} - $BUILD_STATUS:
```

How can I achieve this?